# Need to fetch one documents per user nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents in below mentioned structure:-

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("585d64f356ec921620c5d7c5"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2016-12-23T17:54:59.193Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-12-23T17:54:59.193Z"),
"userid" : ObjectId("5850f42b9a8ea0a43c1355b8"),
"destination" : {
    "id" : ObjectId("584fdcf0e6be59514784e9d4"),
    "lineid" : ObjectId("584f8ddd433c5703acf2618f")
},
"source" : {
    "id" : ObjectId("584fdda2e6be59514784e9df"),
    "lineid" : ObjectId("584fdd2fe6be59514784e9d8")
},
"__v" : 0
```

}

Their are multiple documents in same structure but repeated "userid" field.
**Now i want to fetch document that matches conditions but only one document per user.** I tried using "find" query, "aggregate" and "group" but no success.

I am able to fetch records using this query but the result array is having multiple documents of same user.

```
    Route.find({
    $and : [ {
        $or : [ {
            'source.lineid' : request.payload.sourcelineid
        }, {
            'destination.lineid' : request.payload.destinationlineid
        }, {
            'source.id' : request.payload.source
        }, {
            'destination.id' : request.payload.destination
        } ]
    }, {
        userid : {
            $ne : request.user._id
        }
    } ]
}).sort({
    createdAt : -1
})
.exec(function(err, sameroutes) {
    if (err) {
        reply(err).code(500);
    } else {
        reply(sameroutes).code(200);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregate query I was trying to run was 99% correct, but what I missed was converting all ID values coming from payload to ObjectID. So Correct answer is:-

```
Route.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "userid": { "$ne": request.user._id },
            "$or": [
                { "source.lineid": mongo.ObjectId(request.payload.sourcelineid) }, 
                { "destination.lineid" : mongo.ObjectId(request.payload.destinationlineid) }, 
                { "source.id" : mongo.ObjectId(request.payload.source) }, 
                { "destination.id" : mongo.ObjectId(request.payload.destination) }
            ]
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "userid": 1, "createdAt": -1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$userid",
            "doc_id": { "$first": "$_id" },
            "createdAt": { "$first": "$createdAt" },
            "updatedAt": { "$first": "$updatedAt" },            
            "destination": { "$first": "$destination" },
            "source": { "$first": "$source" }
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, sameroutes) {
    if (err) {
        reply(err).code(500);
    } else {
        reply(sameroutes).code(200);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[`aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate)** method where you can group the documents per user and return the fields using **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** accumulator operators.

Filtering can be done as the initial 
pipeline stage using **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** which uses standard MongoDB queries. Running the following pipeline should give you the desired result:

```
Route.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "userid": { "$ne": request.user._id },
            "$or": [
                { "source.lineid": request.payload.sourcelineid }, 
                { "destination.lineid" : request.payload.destinationlineid }, 
                { "source.id" : request.payload.source }, 
                { "destination.id" : request.payload.destination }
            ]
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "userid": 1, "createdAt": -1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$userid",
            "doc_id": { "$first": "$_id" },
            "createdAt": { "$first": "$createdAt" },
            "updatedAt": { "$first": "$updatedAt" },            
            "destination": { "$first": "$destination" },
            "source": { "$first": "$source" }
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, sameroutes) {
    if (err) {
        reply(err).code(500);
    } else {
        reply(sameroutes).code(200);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello @chridam I tried the same but getting empty array, but matching records exist in database.

Comment: Have you tried running the aggregation pipeline with just the `$match` operator?

Comment: Yes thought to check that atleast. But no success. Same empty array.

Comment: Then that means your query logic is flawed. In the above, you are looking for documents where the user is not the one specified AND any of the conditions in the `$or` statement is true. So that means if there is no match for any of the `$or` expressions then the query won't return any documents, regardless of whether the `"userid": { "$ne": request.user._id }` query part if `true` or `false`.

Comment: I tried to simplified query just to check --- `Route.aggregate([
                  {
                      "$match": {
                       $or:[{
                     userid : {
                  $eq : request.payload.userid
                 }
                       }]
                      }
                  }
              ]).exec(function(err, sameroutes) {
                  if (err) {
                      reply(err).code(500);
                  } else {
                      reply(sameroutes).code(200);
                  }
              });` and got success

Comment: But then i replaced match query--`Route.aggregate([
                  {
                      "$match": {
                       $or:[{
                     sourcelineid : {
                  $eq : request.payload.sourcelineid
                 }
                       }]
                      }
                  }
              ]).exec(function(err, sameroutes) {
                  if (err) {
                      reply(err).code(500);
                  } else {
                      reply(sameroutes).code(200);
                  }
              });` but got empty.

Comment: its giving me empty response.But in structure both are of type: `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`